# jquery bind an ajax loaded element

Tags: data-binding, jquery

I am trying to use a rating plugin which has the following bind command.

```
$("#rateit10b").bind('over', function (event, value) { 
    $(this).attr('title', tooltipvalues[value - 1]); 
});
```

The html is

```
<div class='rateit' id='rateit10b' data-rateit-step='1' >
            </div>
```

But I am loading the html via ajax. The jquery does nt seem to work. Can I use .live() with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.on`, delegation style:

```
$(document).on('over', '#rateit10b', function (event, value) {
```

Several things:

1. Don't use `.live`.  It's removed in jQuery 1.9
2. Use a more specific selector to bind with than `document` if you can
3. Is `over` an event type?  Do you mean `mouseover`?

Comment: actually I am trying use a plugin I found here. http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm  I cannot get the rating div to show the stars bcz i am using ajax load

Comment: @aVC does my suggestion not work?  You could also do the `.bind` call in the callback function of the ajax

Comment: Yes it did! Appreciate comment#1 very much (offcourse others as well, but #1 above all )